# Validate form in php print

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am printing an HTML page in my controller. I need to validate a form input inside that. How can I validate my text input.

Is this possible? Am getting error on JavaScript side.

My code:

```
     print ' <html>
     <form>
         <input type="text" id="cc_number">
     </form>
     <script>

     $('#cc_number').keyup(function(){

        this.value = cc_format(this.value);

     });
     function cc_format(value) 
      {
        var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0- 9]/gi, '');
        var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
        var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
        var parts = []
        for (i=0, len=match.length; i<len; i+=4) {
        parts.push(match.substring(i, i+4))
        }
        if (parts.length) {
        return parts.join(' ')
        } 
         else {
               return value
          }
        }
        </script>
     </html>'
```

Please help.

Comment: @ Gerold Broser thanks for helping me, Am facing error here  .replace(/[^0- 9]/gi, ''); also the edited part

Comment: Escape single quotes, I think they are breaking your code.